# Dynamically added checkbox is not firing onCheck or onUncheck events

Tags: jquery, events, semantic-ui

I have some code which, when ran, loops through some records in an array. For each record, a checkbox is added.

```
$('#manage_time').empty();
$.each(times, function( index, value ) {
    $('#manage_time').append(generate_range_html(value.begin, value.end, value.line, value.absent, value.hours));
});

$('.manage_time_absent').checkbox();
```

As you can see, once all of the checkboxes are added, I'm initializing them after the loop.

Here is my `generate_range_html()` function mentioned in the above code snippet

```
function generate_range_html(begin, end, line, absent, hours) {

    var elem = '\
        <div class="one fields">\
            <div class="field">\
                <div class="ui toggle checkbox manage_time_absent">\
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden">\
                    <label>Absent?</label>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    ';

    return elem;
}
```

For some reason, when I'm checking for the onChecked or the onUnchecked event, I don't get anything in my console. Here is my event listener

```
$('.manage_time_absent').checkbox({
    onChecked: function() {
        console.log($(this));
    },
    onUnchecked: function() {
        console.log($(this));
    }
});
```

I assume this has something to do with the checkbox being dynamically added, and the event listener is only listening for events for elements which already existed on the page.

How can I make this event listener work for anything added dynamically later?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, you're adding the event handlers before the elements exist. To fix this, call `checkbox()` with your settings object again after adding the new checkboxes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What do you mean by "with your settings object"? I'm already calling `checkbox()` again directly after the loop for the elements I added to the DOM.

Comment: I mean you need to include the `{ onChecked: function() { ...` object i the call

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I gotcha, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by moving my `.checkbox()` event handler directly after my loop which adds the checkboxes to the DOM. Instead of just initializing them as checkboxes every time, I attach the event handler directly.

```
$('#manage_time').empty();
$.each(times, function( index, value ) {
    $('#manage_time').append(generate_range_html(value.begin, value.end, value.line, value.absent, value.hours));
});

$('.manage_time_absent').checkbox({
    onChecked: function() {
        console.log($(this));
    },
    onUnchecked: function() {
        console.log($(this));
    }
});
```